# Why Does Autoreversing the Added Animation "Mess Up" the Final Result?

Tags: animation, ios12, swift4.2

I have an application that animates a small, red subview using added animations. The first animation moves the view down by 100 points. The second animation kicks in at the half way point and moves the view to the right by 100 points. The down and the right animations are additive resulting in a diagonal movement toward the lower right. Additionally, both animations are autoreversed so that the view is restored to its original position over the top of the small, green "marker" subview.

[image: simulator]

From the above gif one can see that the view animation behaves as expected until the autoreversing has completed whereupon the view jumps to the left (apparently by 100 points). Typically such a jump would be the result of not having set the state of the view to match the final frame of the animation. However, the view state is indeed being correctly(?) set by the animator's completion method - this seems to be borne out by the information provided by the print statements.

What is the cause of the view's final, leftward jump?

See the relevant code below. A complete project can be downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/verticon/ViewAnimationQuestion)

I have a hunch that the calls to UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses in each of the two animation closures might be the culprit. It is not clear to me that what I have done in that regard is in alignment with the framework's expectations.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var markerView: UIView!
    private var animationView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(tapGestureHandler)))

        let frame = CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY, width: 10, height: 10)

        markerView = UIView(frame: frame)
        markerView.backgroundColor = .green
        view.addSubview(markerView)

        animationView = UIView(frame: frame)
        animationView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(animationView)
    }

    @objc private func tapGestureHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        animate()
    }

    // Move down; half way through begin moving right while still moving down.
    // Autoreverse it.
    private func animate() {
        let distance: CGFloat = 100
        let down = {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.animationView.center.y += distance
        }
        let right = {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.animationView.center.x += distance
        }

        print("\nCenter: \(self.animationView.center)")

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear, animations: down)
        animator.addAnimations(right, delayFactor: 0.5)
        animator.addCompletion { _ in
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
            self.animationView.center.x -= distance
            self.animationView.center.y -= distance
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

I have added two other versions of the animate method which are informative. Based upon what I learned from these two versions, I altered the title of this question.

animate2: The calls to UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses have been commented out in each of the down and right animation functions. This modified code functions as expected. Of course we do not get the smooth autoreversing effect.

```
extension ViewController {

        private func animate2() {
        let distance: CGFloat = 100
        let down = {
            //UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.animationView.center.y += distance
        }
        let right = {
            //UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.animationView.center.x += distance
        }

        print("\nCenter: \(self.animationView.center)")

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear, animations: down)
        animator.addAnimations(right, delayFactor: 0.5)
        animator.addCompletion { _ in
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
            self.animationView.center.x -= distance
            self.animationView.center.y -= distance
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

[image]

animate3: The addition of the second (i.e. right) animation is commented out. This modified code functions as expected. Of course we do not get the movement to the right.

```
extension ViewController {

    private func animate3() {
        let distance: CGFloat = 100
        let down = {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.animationView.center.y += distance
        }
        let right = {
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses(true)
            self.animationView.center.x += distance
        }

        print("\nCenter: \(self.animationView.center)")

        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear, animations: down)
        //animator.addAnimations(right, delayFactor: 0.5)
        animator.addCompletion { _ in
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
            self.animationView.center.y -= distance
            //self.animationView.center.x -= distance
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

[image]

It appears that calling UIView.setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses in both of the animation functions is "messing things up". It is not clear to me if this can be rightly be regarded as an iOS bug.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the line under your animate() method ::

```
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, curve: .linear, animations: down)
        animator.addAnimations(right, delayFactor: 0.5)
        animator.addCompletion { _ in
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
            //self.animationView.center.x -= distance //<--- Comment or remove this line.
            self.animationView.center.y -= distance
            print("Center: \(self.animationView.center)")
        }
```

Comment: Hello Nikunj. Doing as you suggest produces the desired visual effect. But the value of the view's center, as reported by the print statements, still does not match the screen.